# Durable function app high memory use, DurableTask.Core.History.TaskCompletedEvent filling the heap

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a durable function app that is using a lot of memory. I took a snapshot in Visual Studia, and the heap is filling up with `DurableTask.Core.History.TaskCompletedEvent`.

Is there a way to limit these?

I think I need to set a durableTask option, like in `DurableTaskOptions`. Something like `HistorySize` or `MaxCompletedOrchestrations`, but I'm not having any luck. I've tried this using `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask` version 2.9.0 and the latest version 2.9.4, but none of the fields look promising.